# webservice SOAP Response

Tags: web-services, soap

i create this to get soap response this is my code

```
$requestParams = array(

            'userName'=>'*********',
            'password'=>'*******',
            'customerReferenceNo' =>'100014246' ,
            'CostCenterCode'=>'100014246',
            'consigneeName'=>'Muhammad yousuf',
    );enter code here
    $client = new SoapClient('http://202.61.51.93:6265?WSDL');
    $response = $client->InsertData($requestParams);
    $getDetail =$response->InsertDataResult;


    print_r($response);
```

but it show invalid service code in response what will be the issue??

Comment: It might be helpful to put the exact contents of the print_r($response).

Comment: stdClass Object ( [InsertDataResult] => Invalid Service code. )